# Issue with 'Align to Artboard' in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, artboard

I drew a **Polar Grid** and tried to align it **centre horizontally and vertically** in the artboard. But it's aligning to somewhere else.

[image: Align to Pixel Grid is already unchecked]

**Align to Pixel Grid** is already unchecked. I'm not facing this issue, if I draw with other shape tools such as **Rectangle tool**, **Ellipse tool** and all.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have changed the artboard size, Illustrator orients to the original center, not the new center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a bug (in which case it might be worth reporting to Adobe) or it could just be a temporary glitch (in which case I would suggest restarting Illustrator, creating a new document and seeing if it happens again. Either way, I can't replicate the problem.

However, there is a quick workaround for placing something centrally in an artboard. Simply select the item or items that you want to place, cut them, fit the artboard to the the window and then paste. The contents of the clipboard will be dropped in the middle of the artboard by default.

For speed, select your items, hold down command (or control for PC) and then hit X then 0 (zero) then V.